# Accidentally merged one iCloud Photos library with another -- how to revert back?

Tags: photos.app, data-synchronization, photo-stream

Here's the tick-tock of how this happened:

- Daughter A had an old iPad that she rarely used, so she offered to give it to Daughter B.
- Daughter A signed out of her iCloud account on the iPad, and (when prompted) indicated that she wanted to remove all of her personal info (Contacts, Calendar, etc.) from the iPad.  *However*, apparently doing this does *not* remove photos that are locally stored on the iPad...  something that she did not realize and did not check before handing the iPad over to its new owner.
- Daughter B signed into her iCloud account on the iPad.  Later that day she opened the Photos app and saw not only her own photos, but also all of Daughter A's photos.  Whoops!
- Daughter B then looked on her phone and saw that there, too, all of Daughter A's photos were mixed in with her own.

Is there any way to disentangle these two photo libraries? Can I revert Daughter B's library back to the state it was in 24 or 48 hours ago?  (Searching online for "revert Photos library" brings up dozens of sites about restoring deleted photos, which is not the problem I'm having.)

Comment: On B's iPhone she can search (in Photos app) for "iPad" and it will show all photos created with an iPad (but not iPhone). Can be more precise with iPad model type. Delete them! If it were me, I would make sure I had a backup (outside iCloud) of all photos first.

Comment: How many is "all"?  A hundred is meh, delete them, a thousand is maybe find some solution.  For me, even a thousand, I'd just delete them.  Yet another reason to never bother with Photos.app or iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: @Gilby unfortunately I don't think Daughter A's phoyos were *created* on the iPad. They were taken with her phone, synced to her iPad, and somehow were left behind when she signed out of her iCloud account.

Comment: @MarcWilson We are definitely in the "maybe a thousand" territory. Going through them one by one could take weeks.

Comment: Do they both have same model of iPhone?

Comment: Call Apple as soon as possible and ask if they can restore the photo library. They may or may not have a backup that is suitably timed but they sometimes do

Comment: Do you have a Mac as well (because some things are easier done on a proper computer)? Is there anything in the metadata of the photos which would allow to bulk-select them (different iPhone models from A and B, different locations etc.), or at least part of them?

Comment: @Ezekiel Is there any reference which indicates that Apple does user-level restores?

Comment: Presumably, this was all caused because the iPad was never fully reset, so still belongs to the same iCloud account.

Comment: Is there no backup?

Comment: @benwiggy Not sure a backup would help. My understanding (maybe wrong) is that iPhone backups to iCloud don't include phone data which is already in iCloud (e.g. photos).

Comment: @Tetsujin correct, it was not fully reset -- but it was signed out of the old iCloud account, which I (apparently incorrectly) assumed would be good enough for our purposes

Comment: Each user needs their own Apple ID, even if they're within a Family Sharing account. Each device needs to be 'owned' by the ID that uses it, otherwise 'accidental' sharing & merging can happen. By default all devices owned by a single ID will share content. You cannot fully sign a phone out of its Apple ID, unless you reset it [& release it from Find My].

Comment: @Tetsujin -- Each user *has* their own Apple ID, and each device *is* owned by the ID that uses it. The problem is that when Daughter A signed out from the iCloud account on her iPad she did not remove her photos from it, so when Daughter B signed into *her* account the libraries merged.

Comment: @nohillside People on reddit have countlessly said that Apple was able to provide an account-level restore of data. The timeframes available for restore have always been limited and it's always all or nothing.

Comment: @Ezekiel any idea how to request this? I contacted Apple tech support on Tuesday and was told this was not possible

Comment: @mweiss It's possible they will only service it in the case of data loss, so you may have to frame the question differently. It's also possible policies have changed. You could ask to speak to a supervisor to confirm, as the first level tech support is unlikely to have access to do it, if it is possible